# Unable to Copy Files in PowerShell using PSSession and Copy-Item cmdlet without a Method Invocation Error

Tags: windows-10, powershell, data-transfer, powershell-5.0

I have a PowerShell script that attempts to transfer files from an old machine to a new one. This is occuring on Windows 10 with PowerShell v5. For this purpose I'd prefer to use PSSession to transfer files. However, certain files throw the below error:

```
Copy-Item : Method invocation failed because [System.IO.MemoryStream] does not contain a method named 'new'.
At C:\Users\username\Desktop\Import-ComputerData.ps1:153 char:13
+             Copy-Item -Path "C:\users\$UserName\Desktop" -Destination ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException,WriteException
```

Here is the relevant code causing this:

```
    $PSSession = New-PSSession -Computername $ComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable PSSessionError
    ...
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\users\$UserName\Desktop" -Destination "C:\users\$UserName\" -Recurse -FromSession $PSSession -PassThru -Force
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\users\$UserName\Documents" -Destination "C:\users\$UserName\" -Recurse -FromSession $PSSession -PassThru -Force
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\users\$UserName\Favorites" -Destination "C:\users\$UserName\" -Recurse -FromSession $PSSession -PassThru -Force
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\users\$UserName\Pictures" -Destination "C:\users\$UserName\" -Recurse -FromSession $PSSession -PassThru -Force
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\users\$UserName\Downloads" -Destination "C:\users\$UserName\Downloads\Old Downloads" -Recurse -FromSession $PSSession -PassThru -Force
    ...
    Remove-PSSession $PSSession
```

The script is ran on the new PC receiving the files from the old machine. The aforementioned error only happens during the copying process. I thought I had the cause narrowed down to files downloaded from the Internet and needed to be "Unblocked" as the entire Downloads folder never transferred.

I tried adding the following code before my Copy-Item cmdlets and I still get the same errors:

```
        Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {
            # This unblocks all internet downloaded files. Only use on trusted files.
            Get-ChildItem "c:\users\$UserName\*" -Recurse | Unblock-File 
        }
```

Any insight on how to get around this would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `::new` anywhere in the code you didn't include in your post?
 As part of the memory stream? If you are using `[System.IO.MemoryStream]::new`, try instead using `[System.IO.MemoryStream]`.

Comment: @root I don't have that snippet anywhere in my code. The error appears to appear as part of the copying process and the affected files are downloaded from the internet or another computer.

Comment: I ask because of some of the comments here: https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2016/02/26/large-file-upload-in-sharepoint-online-with-csom-powershell/. They also speak to file size contributing to the error.

Comment: @root Maybe that was the case for another use of that snippet but I encountered this same error today when some files wouldn't transfer that were as low as 1KB in size. I haven't found a link I am certain of yet but I still think it could be related to internet or "untrusted" files from a source other than the source machine

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a utility to perform this from C# before PowerShell had support by using the buffer to send nibbles of the file then reassembling on the remote machine through WinRM calls.  It's a little circuitous and I've not tested it over 100MB but it works really well up to that.  You can look at the C# file here and could copy out the relavent pieces of PowerShell and try that... https://github.com/NaosProject/Naos.WinRM/blob/master/Naos.WinRM/Naos.WinRM.cs